# Mouse right click and open in new tab does not work in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to open link in new tab only when right click on mouse and select open in new tab.

```
<a ng-href="" ng-click="goState(item.state)">
```

this is my javascript function.

```
scope.goState = function (state: any): void {                        
    $state.go(state);
};
```

It calls function and goes to new page, when perform click, but this does not work when I right click on mouse and select new tab.

I used `<a ng-href="goState(item.state)">` and `<a ng-href="{{ item.state }}">` then it shows in browser `Cannot GET /app.dashboard` where item.state = app.dashboard.

can anyone give me a good way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using angular ui router then try this:

```
<a ng-href="{{ href(item.state) }}">
```

and

```
scope.href = function (state: any): void {                        
    $state.href(state);
};
```

the docs about [$state.href()](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#statehrefstateorname--params--options)

Comment: it didn't work for me .  this is how url show in browser http://localhost/href(item.state) and this is browser content Cannot GET /href(item.state)

Comment: @User1 Try wrapping in `{{ }}`

Comment: if i Add ng-href="{{ href(item.state) }}" then it does not give me select open in new tab when right click on mouse

Answer (score 0):

I finally I was able to solve my problem

```
<a ng-href="{{ href(item.state) }}">
```

Comment: learn to mark the correct answer. cuz this already this answer is provided by @jcubic